# TPL DataFlow memory leak

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I've developed a multiple data pipelines using **TPL DataFlow v5.0** which any pipeline contains TPL blocks.

***Each pipeline looks like this:***

**BufferBlock** - receives udp packets from multiple clients and encapsulate them according to my case.

**TransformBlock** - receives encapsulated packets and validate each message.

**TransformBlock** - receives valid packets and decode them.

**BroadcastBlock** - broadcast the decoded messages to 2 separate Action Blocks(writing into local files ,sending them to external service)

So far everything worked perfectly except the memory use.

No matter what the frequency of the incoming packets , the memory use always growing and seems that no cleanup has made.

I've try many different configurations for each block (Bounded Capacity etc..) and didn't figure it out.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Sorry, but you cannot claim to have a memory leak here without showing the appropriate evidence you have gathered from your memory profiling sessions. Because 9 times out of 10, its not a memory leak, its just the way .net works. And even if you do have a real memory leak, 99 times out of 100 its your code that is at fault and not the BCL code

Comment: Are all blocks configured with `BoundedCapacity`, or only some of them?

Comment: What happens to _in_valid packets?

Comment: 1. when receiving from single client udp packets each 30 ms ,  after 1 hour , the memory goes to 1GB at any running! 
by the way , pretty good chance that im doing something wrong here .
2. all blocks configured to bounded capacity.  
3. invalid packets linked to NullTargetBlock

Comment: You really need to profile your app to see whats hanging around between gc's, its the only way to be certain and work out what is causing an issue without trying to eyeball code. It could be as easy as keeping things off the Large Object Heap

Comment: @ChenBenHamo post your code then. Perhaps the blocks are too slow to process all messages so they pile up. Or perhaps the code is allocating a lot of temporary objects, resulting in 1GB RAM usage. Dataflow may have nothing to do with the leak

Comment: @ChenBenHamo string modifications allocate new strings which results in lots of temporary objects. That's why StringBuilder is used instead. Adding items to lists one by one results in buffer reallocations and temporary objects. That's why almost all containers have constructors with a `capacity` parameter to preallocate the buffer. If you create arrays manually, you create extra objects that need to be garbage collected. That's why ArrayPool is used, to allow reusing buffers

Comment: Inefficient code may not cause a problem if it's executed once every few minutes, but a Dataflow delegate (the code we write to process messages) can execute thousands of times a second. Inefficiencies in high-frequency code have a far larger impact

Comment: We can only guess. You can profile.

Comment: Can you include in the question how you feed the entry point of the pipeline (the `BufferBlock`) with UDP packets?

Comment: after a lot of testes I can see clearly 1 thing:
When I'm simulate data in very fast frequency the GC is start working and the memory usage stay balanced. but when I'm simulating data in frequency of my case the memory just keep going slowly but always growing without GC cleanup.

Comment: Hi there , I created a Mock project. you can check it on https://github.com/chenbh-dev/ConsoleApp4/tree/master/ConsoleApp4. the main issue that I didn't understand is why when im calling to Stop method the memory usage stay where it is instead of cleaning up.